# Can questions be considered duplicates if no answer is applicable to both?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I asked [a question about verifying integrity of sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509487/whats-the-official-method-for-checking-integrity-of-a-source-package). It got closed as duplicate as duplicate of [a similar but different question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56841/gpg-cant-check-signature).

The other question was not about how to verify the integrity, but rather about how to fix a particular warning message. The answers explain how to remove the warning message.

Later I found the answer to my own question. It turns out the warning is triggered by a check which is sort of redundant, because the real integrity check is done by a hash tree totally unrelated to the signature generating the warning.

This means taking any of the answers to that old question and apply to my question, it would in fact be an incorrect answer.

On the other hand, the answer I found to my own question tells me, that the warning can be safely ignored, because it is not part of the integrity check. This would not be a good answer to the old question about how to fix the warning. If you ask how to fix a warning, the answer you are looking for is not to just ignore it.

Given that a correct answer to one question would be an incorrect answer to the other question and vice-versa, can they still be considered duplicates?

Comment: Your question is not closed, never has been, so go post your answer :-)

Comment: @Seth You are right. I may have been confused. Perhaps I should just delete this meta question then.

Comment: @Seth It did get closed as duplicate eventually, though I did get to answer it first. So my question still stands. How can two questions be considered duplicates, when a correct answer to one question would be incorrect on the other and vice-versa?

Comment: Sometimes people don't read, or don't understand or even something else. People are human you know ;) I have reopened your question.